# How to move a game object in the forwrard direction of an other game object Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am making a camera controller script and I struggle a lot with vectors. I am making a rts-like camera and I had a lot of trouble doing everything, but almost all is working now except one thing : the mouse scroll.

To achieve this camera, I had to put it in a empty game object to reset it's rotation (because the camera has some rotation (65 deg on the x), and for things like movements it's simpler, so I can use the transform.forward things (which would go forward and down if the camera was moving and not its parent)).

Currently, my mouse scroll is moving the camera up and down, but I would like it to go forward (with the transform.forward of the camera, so it's like a zoom), but because the cam is in a game object, how do I move the game object in the direction of the camera transform.forward.

Here is my code so far:

```
public class CameraController : MonoBehaviour
{

    public float panSpeed = 50f;
    public float rotSpeed = 50f;
    //marge pour le déplacement à la souris
    public float scrollSpeed = 5f;
    public float dragSpeed = 5f;
    private Vector3 dragOrigin;
    
    [Header("Y")]
    public float minY = 10f;
    public float maxY = 80f;

    [Header("X")]
    public float minX = 10f;
    public float maxX = 80f;

    [Header("Z")]
    public float minZ = 10f;
    public float maxZ = 80f;

    void Update()
    {
        Vector3 newPos = transform.position;

        if(GameManager.gameIsOver)
        {
            //plus pouvoir controller la cam lors du game over
            this.enabled = false;
            return;
        }

        //déplacement avant
        if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W))
        {
            newPos += new Vector3(this.transform.forward.x,0,this.transform.forward.z) * panSpeed * Time.unscaledDeltaTime;
        } 

        //déplacement arrière
        if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S))
        {
             newPos += new Vector3(-this.transform.forward.x,0,-this.transform.forward.z) * panSpeed * Time.unscaledDeltaTime;
        } 

        //déplacement gauche
        if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A))
        {
            newPos += -transform.right * panSpeed * Time.unscaledDeltaTime;
        }

        //déplacement droite
        if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D))
        {
            newPos += transform.right * panSpeed * Time.unscaledDeltaTime;
        }

        //rotation droite
        if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Q))
        {
            transform.Rotate(Vector3.down * rotSpeed * Time.unscaledDeltaTime, Space.World);
        }

        //rotation gauche
        if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.E))
        {
            transform.Rotate(Vector3.up * rotSpeed * Time.unscaledDeltaTime, Space.World);
        }

        //chopper la molette (molette = un axis de la souris aussi)
        float scroll = Input.GetAxis("Mouse ScrollWheel");

        //zoomer/dezoomer
        newPos.y -= scroll * 1000 * scrollSpeed * Time.unscaledDeltaTime;
        //bloquer la cam entre le min et le max
        newPos.y = Mathf.Clamp(newPos.y, minY, maxY);
        newPos.x = Mathf.Clamp(newPos.x, minX, maxX);
        newPos.z = Mathf.Clamp(newPos.z, minZ, maxZ);
        transform.position = newPos;

        UpdateDrag();
    }

    void UpdateDrag()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(2))
        {
            dragOrigin = Input.mousePosition;
        }
 
        if (Input.GetMouseButton(2))
        {
            Vector3 pos = Camera.main.ScreenToViewportPoint(Input.mousePosition - dragOrigin);
            Vector3 move = new Vector3(pos.x * dragSpeed, 0, pos.y * dragSpeed);
 
            transform.Translate(-move, Space.Self);
            dragOrigin = Input.mousePosition; 
        }
 
    }


}
```

I don't know if my problem is clear enough, but thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the camera controller a component of the parent? If yes, good. Give it a reference to your child object with the camera and when scrolling change the position of the child not the parent.

When you now scroll the wheel, use `camera.forward`, with camera being the child.
For drag and everything else you still change the position of the parent object.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot ! It worked.

Here is the code:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class CameraController : MonoBehaviour
{

    public float panSpeed = 50f;
    public float rotSpeed = 50f;
    //marge pour le déplacement à la souris
    public float scrollSpeed = 5f;
    public float dragSpeed = 5f;
    private Vector3 dragOrigin;
    
    [Header("Y")]
    public float minY = 10f;
    public float maxY = 80f;

    [Header("X")]
    public float minX = 10f;
    public float maxX = 80f;

    [Header("Z")]
    public float minZ = 10f;
    public float maxZ = 80f;

    public GameObject cam;

    void Update()
    {
        Vector3 newPos = transform.position;
        Vector3 newCamPos = cam.transform.localPosition;

        if(GameManager.gameIsOver)
        {
            //plus pouvoir controller la cam lors du game over
            this.enabled = false;
            return;
        }

        //déplacement avant
        if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W))
        {
            newPos += new Vector3(this.transform.forward.x,0,this.transform.forward.z) * panSpeed * Time.unscaledDeltaTime;
        } 

        //déplacement arrière
        if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S))
        {
             newPos += new Vector3(-this.transform.forward.x,0,-this.transform.forward.z) * panSpeed * Time.unscaledDeltaTime;
        } 

        //déplacement gauche
        if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A))
        {
            newPos += -transform.right * panSpeed * Time.unscaledDeltaTime;
        }

        //déplacement droite
        if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D))
        {
            newPos += transform.right * panSpeed * Time.unscaledDeltaTime;
        }

        //rotation droite
        if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Q))
        {
            transform.Rotate(Vector3.down * rotSpeed * Time.unscaledDeltaTime, Space.World);
        }

        //rotation gauche
        if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.E))
        {
            transform.Rotate(Vector3.up * rotSpeed * Time.unscaledDeltaTime, Space.World);
        }

        //chopper la molette (molette = un axis de la souris aussi)
        float scroll = Input.GetAxis("Mouse ScrollWheel");

        //zoomer/dezoomer
        newCamPos -= cam.transform.forward * scroll * 1000 * scrollSpeed * Time.unscaledDeltaTime;
        //bloquer la cam entre le min et le max
        // newCamPos.y = Mathf.Clamp(newCamPos.y, minY, maxY);
        newPos.x = Mathf.Clamp(newPos.x, minX, maxX);
        newPos.z = Mathf.Clamp(newPos.z, minZ, maxZ);
        transform.position = newPos;
        cam.transform.localPosition = newCamPos;

        UpdateDrag();
    }

    void UpdateDrag()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(2))
        {
            dragOrigin = Input.mousePosition;
        }
 
        if (Input.GetMouseButton(2))
        {
            Vector3 pos = Camera.main.ScreenToViewportPoint(Input.mousePosition - dragOrigin);
            Vector3 move = new Vector3(pos.x * dragSpeed, 0, pos.y * dragSpeed);
 
            transform.Translate(-move, Space.Self);
            dragOrigin = Input.mousePosition; 
        }
 
    }


}
```

I just have some problems because I can't limit the movements the way it was done before.

```
// newCamPos.y = Mathf.Clamp(newCamPos.y, minY, maxY);
```

This is not working anymore because the movement is also affecting the z axis.

Anyway I really appreciated your help !